# Label Product of a Graph with itself

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

> **Defn** Let $\mathcal{G}=(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E})$ and $\mathcal{G}' = (\mathcal{V}', \mathcal{E}')$ be two labeled graphs with alphabet $\mathcal{A}$. The *labeled graph product* $\mathcal{G} * \mathcal{G}'$ is defined as follows:
>
> - The vertex set of $\mathcal{G} * \mathcal{G}'$ is the Cartesian product $\mathcal{V} \times \mathcal{V}'$.
> - Given $(g, g')$ and $(h, h') \in \mathcal{V} \times \mathcal{V}'$ and $a \in \mathcal{A}$, there is a labeled edge $(g,g') \overset{a}{\longrightarrow} (h,h')$ if and only if there is an edge $g \overset{a}{\longrightarrow} h$ in $\mathcal{G}$ and an edge $g' \overset{a}{\longrightarrow} h'$ in $\mathcal{G}'$.

Given a labeled graph $\mathcal{G}$, I am trying to efficiently implement the labeled graph product $\mathcal{G}*\mathcal{G}$. If it helps, the graphs I'm concerned with will always have the following properties:

- $\mathcal{G}$ will be *right-resolving* (aka a Shannon graph), that is, all edges leaving a given vertex bear distinct labels.
- For each label $a \in \mathcal{A}$ and each vertex $v \in \mathcal{V}$, there is an edge leaving $v$ with label $a$, i.e., $v \overset{a}{\longrightarrow} \dots$.

For example, consider the graph

```
graph= {{1 -> 3, "a"}, {1 -> 5, "b"}, {2 -> 1, "a"}, {3 -> 2, "a"}, {3 -> 4, "b"}, {4 -> 1, "a"}, {5 -> 6, "a"}, {5 -> 4, "b"}, {6 -> 1,"a"}, {0 -> 0, "a"}, {0 -> 0, "b"}, {2 -> 0, "b"}, {4 -> 0,  "b"}, {6 -> 0, "b"}}
```

I have approached this problem by first defining a function that, given a vertex and a label, returns the target of the corresponding edge:

```
 leavingEdgeTarget[vertex_, edgeLabel_, graph_] := Select[Select[graph, #[[1, 1]] == vertex &], #[[2]] == edgeLabel &][[ 1, 1, 2]]
```

and then using the following function:

```
 labelProduct[graph_] := With[
  {vertexList = VertexList@Graph@graph[[All, 1]],
  alphabet = Union@graph[[All, 2]]}, 
    Flatten[#, 2] &@
     ParallelTable[{{v1,v2} -> 
      {leavingEdgeTarget[v1, label,graph], 
       leavingEdgeTarget[v2, label, graph]}, 
      label},
       {v1, vertexList}, 
       {v2, vertexList},
       {label, alphabet}
      ]
  ]
```

So for example, `labelProduct[graph]` returns the following graph with 49 vertices and 98 edges:

```
{{{1,1}->{3,3},"a"}, {{1,1}->{5,5}, "b"}, {{1,3}->{3,2},"a"},...,{{0,0}->{0,0},"b"}}
```

#### Q: How can I speed this up?

For small graphs, this runs reasonably fast (and seems to get a very nice speedup from the use of `ParallelTable`). However, it starts to take quite a while for larger graphs (100+ vertices). Consider the graph

```
SeedRandom[0];
n = 100;
randomGraph = 
  Flatten[#, 1]&@
   Table[{i -> RandomInteger[{1, n}], label},
         {i, 1, n}, 
         {label, Range[3]}
        ];
```

On my machine (32GB memory, 8 logical cores @3.7GHz) I get the following values for `labelProduct[randomGraph];//AbsoluteTiming` different values of `n`:

```
  n   AbsoluteTiming
 10   0.022
 20   0.072
 50   0.600
100   4.418
150  14.524
200  34.193
250  66.879
500  529.8=8m49.8s
```

I can achieve a small timing benefit by only generating the edges $(i,j)\overset{a}{\longrightarrow}(i', j')$ with $i \leq j$ and then find the remaining edges in the label product by noting that there is also an edge $(j,i)\overset{a}{\longrightarrow}(j',i')$, but this only has a speedup by a factor of roughly $1/2$.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just group vertices by their labels, and then use [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples) to generate the new vertices? For example:

```
grp = GroupBy[graph, Last -> First, Replace[Tuples[#,2], t_ :> Thread[t, Rule], {1}]&]
```

> <|"a" -> {{1, 1} -> {3, 3}, {1, 2} -> {3, 1}, {1, 3} -> {3, 2}, {1, 4} -> {3, 
>        1}, {1, 5} -> {3, 6}, {1, 6} -> {3, 1}, {1, 0} -> {3, 0}, {2, 1} -> {1, 
>        3}, {2, 2} -> {1, 1}, {2, 3} -> {1, 2}, {2, 4} -> {1, 1}, {2, 5} -> {1, 
>        6}, {2, 6} -> {1, 1}, {2, 0} -> {1, 0}, {3, 1} -> {2, 3}, {3, 2} -> {2, 
>        1}, {3, 3} -> {2, 2}, {3, 4} -> {2, 1}, {3, 5} -> {2, 6}, {3, 6} -> {2, 
>        1}, {3, 0} -> {2, 0}, {4, 1} -> {1, 3}, {4, 2} -> {1, 1}, {4, 3} -> {1, 
>        2}, {4, 4} -> {1, 1}, {4, 5} -> {1, 6}, {4, 6} -> {1, 1}, {4, 0} -> {1, 
>        0}, {5, 1} -> {6, 3}, {5, 2} -> {6, 1}, {5, 3} -> {6, 2}, {5, 4} -> {6, 
>        1}, {5, 5} -> {6, 6}, {5, 6} -> {6, 1}, {5, 0} -> {6, 0}, {6, 1} -> {1, 
>        3}, {6, 2} -> {1, 1}, {6, 3} -> {1, 2}, {6, 4} -> {1, 1}, {6, 5} -> {1, 
>        6}, {6, 6} -> {1, 1}, {6, 0} -> {1, 0}, {0, 1} -> {0, 3}, {0, 2} -> {0, 
>        1}, {0, 3} -> {0, 2}, {0, 4} -> {0, 1}, {0, 5} -> {0, 6}, {0, 6} -> {0, 
>        1}, {0, 0} -> {0, 0}}, 
>    "b" -> {{1, 1} -> {5, 5}, {1, 3} -> {5, 4}, {1, 5} -> {5, 4}, {1, 0} -> {5, 
>        0}, {1, 2} -> {5, 0}, {1, 4} -> {5, 0}, {1, 6} -> {5, 0}, {3, 1} -> {4, 
>        5}, {3, 3} -> {4, 4}, {3, 5} -> {4, 4}, {3, 0} -> {4, 0}, {3, 2} -> {4, 
>        0}, {3, 4} -> {4, 0}, {3, 6} -> {4, 0}, {5, 1} -> {4, 5}, {5, 3} -> {4, 
>        4}, {5, 5} -> {4, 4}, {5, 0} -> {4, 0}, {5, 2} -> {4, 0}, {5, 4} -> {4, 
>        0}, {5, 6} -> {4, 0}, {0, 1} -> {0, 5}, {0, 3} -> {0, 4}, {0, 5} -> {0, 
>        4}, {0, 0} -> {0, 0}, {0, 2} -> {0, 0}, {0, 4} -> {0, 0}, {0, 6} -> {0, 
>        0}, {2, 1} -> {0, 5}, {2, 3} -> {0, 4}, {2, 5} -> {0, 4}, {2, 0} -> {0, 
>        0}, {2, 2} -> {0, 0}, {2, 4} -> {0, 0}, {2, 6} -> {0, 0}, {4, 1} -> {0, 
>        5}, {4, 3} -> {0, 4}, {4, 5} -> {0, 4}, {4, 0} -> {0, 0}, {4, 2} -> {0, 
>        0}, {4, 4} -> {0, 0}, {4, 6} -> {0, 0}, {6, 1} -> {0, 5}, {6, 3} -> {0, 
>        4}, {6, 5} -> {0, 4}, {6, 0} -> {0, 0}, {6, 2} -> {0, 0}, {6, 4} -> {0, 
>        0}, {6, 6} -> {0, 0}}|>

Then, your desired edges can be obtained with:

```
gproduct = Catenate @ KeyValueMap[Function[{k, v}, Thread[{v,k}]]] @ grp
```

> {{{1, 1} -> {3, 3}, "a"}, {{1, 2} -> {3, 1}, "a"}, {{1, 3} -> {3, 2}, 
>     "a"}, {{1, 4} -> {3, 1}, "a"}, {{1, 5} -> {3, 6}, "a"}, {{1, 6} -> {3, 1}, 
>     "a"}, {{1, 0} -> {3, 0}, "a"}, {{2, 1} -> {1, 3}, "a"}, {{2, 2} -> {1, 1}, 
>     "a"}, {{2, 3} -> {1, 2}, "a"}, {{2, 4} -> {1, 1}, "a"}, {{2, 5} -> {1, 6}, 
>     "a"}, {{2, 6} -> {1, 1}, "a"}, {{2, 0} -> {1, 0}, "a"}, {{3, 1} -> {2, 3}, 
>     "a"}, {{3, 2} -> {2, 1}, "a"}, {{3, 3} -> {2, 2}, "a"}, {{3, 4} -> {2, 1}, 
>     "a"}, {{3, 5} -> {2, 6}, "a"}, {{3, 6} -> {2, 1}, "a"}, {{3, 0} -> {2, 0}, 
>     "a"}, {{4, 1} -> {1, 3}, "a"}, {{4, 2} -> {1, 1}, "a"}, {{4, 3} -> {1, 2}, 
>     "a"}, {{4, 4} -> {1, 1}, "a"}, {{4, 5} -> {1, 6}, "a"}, {{4, 6} -> {1, 1}, 
>     "a"}, {{4, 0} -> {1, 0}, "a"}, {{5, 1} -> {6, 3}, "a"}, {{5, 2} -> {6, 1}, 
>     "a"}, {{5, 3} -> {6, 2}, "a"}, {{5, 4} -> {6, 1}, "a"}, {{5, 5} -> {6, 6}, 
>     "a"}, {{5, 6} -> {6, 1}, "a"}, {{5, 0} -> {6, 0}, "a"}, {{6, 1} -> {1, 3}, 
>     "a"}, {{6, 2} -> {1, 1}, "a"}, {{6, 3} -> {1, 2}, "a"}, {{6, 4} -> {1, 1}, 
>     "a"}, {{6, 5} -> {1, 6}, "a"}, {{6, 6} -> {1, 1}, "a"}, {{6, 0} -> {1, 0}, 
>     "a"}, {{0, 1} -> {0, 3}, "a"}, {{0, 2} -> {0, 1}, "a"}, {{0, 3} -> {0, 2}, 
>     "a"}, {{0, 4} -> {0, 1}, "a"}, {{0, 5} -> {0, 6}, "a"}, {{0, 6} -> {0, 1}, 
>     "a"}, {{0, 0} -> {0, 0}, "a"}, {{1, 1} -> {5, 5}, "b"}, {{1, 3} -> {5, 4}, 
>     "b"}, {{1, 5} -> {5, 4}, "b"}, {{1, 0} -> {5, 0}, "b"}, {{1, 2} -> {5, 0}, 
>     "b"}, {{1, 4} -> {5, 0}, "b"}, {{1, 6} -> {5, 0}, "b"}, {{3, 1} -> {4, 5}, 
>     "b"}, {{3, 3} -> {4, 4}, "b"}, {{3, 5} -> {4, 4}, "b"}, {{3, 0} -> {4, 0}, 
>     "b"}, {{3, 2} -> {4, 0}, "b"}, {{3, 4} -> {4, 0}, "b"}, {{3, 6} -> {4, 0}, 
>     "b"}, {{5, 1} -> {4, 5}, "b"}, {{5, 3} -> {4, 4}, "b"}, {{5, 5} -> {4, 4}, 
>     "b"}, {{5, 0} -> {4, 0}, "b"}, {{5, 2} -> {4, 0}, "b"}, {{5, 4} -> {4, 0}, 
>     "b"}, {{5, 6} -> {4, 0}, "b"}, {{0, 1} -> {0, 5}, "b"}, {{0, 3} -> {0, 4}, 
>     "b"}, {{0, 5} -> {0, 4}, "b"}, {{0, 0} -> {0, 0}, "b"}, {{0, 2} -> {0, 0}, 
>     "b"}, {{0, 4} -> {0, 0}, "b"}, {{0, 6} -> {0, 0}, "b"}, {{2, 1} -> {0, 5}, 
>     "b"}, {{2, 3} -> {0, 4}, "b"}, {{2, 5} -> {0, 4}, "b"}, {{2, 0} -> {0, 0}, 
>     "b"}, {{2, 2} -> {0, 0}, "b"}, {{2, 4} -> {0, 0}, "b"}, {{2, 6} -> {0, 0}, 
>     "b"}, {{4, 1} -> {0, 5}, "b"}, {{4, 3} -> {0, 4}, "b"}, {{4, 5} -> {0, 4}, 
>     "b"}, {{4, 0} -> {0, 0}, "b"}, {{4, 2} -> {0, 0}, "b"}, {{4, 4} -> {0, 0}, 
>     "b"}, {{4, 6} -> {0, 0}, "b"}, {{6, 1} -> {0, 5}, "b"}, {{6, 3} -> {0, 4}, 
>     "b"}, {{6, 5} -> {0, 4}, "b"}, {{6, 0} -> {0, 0}, "b"}, {{6, 2} -> {0, 0}, 
>     "b"}, {{6, 4} -> {0, 0}, "b"}, {{6, 6} -> {0, 0}, "b"}}

which is the same as your result up to ordering.

Comment: Wow! Very nice...I may need to finally figure out associations. Getting a timing value of `0.75` for `n=500` instead of 8.5minutes. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure whether my thinking is correct. But let's see.

Let's start with two random labeled graphs.

```
SeedRandom[0];
n = 100;
G = Flatten[#, 1] &@ Table[{i -> RandomInteger[{1, n}], label}, {i, 1, n}, {label,Range[3]}];
H = Flatten[#, 1] &@ Table[{i -> RandomInteger[{1, n}], label}, {i, 1, n}, {label, Range[3]}];
```

Personally, I don't like lists of rules. I prefer packed arrays for their efficiency. Moreover, I'd like to have the labels in front for later use. So, let's reorder.

```
Gpat = Developer`ToPackedArray[Block[{Rule = Sequence}, G]][[All, {3, 1, 2}]];
Hpat = Developer`ToPackedArray[Block[{Rule = Sequence}, H]][[All, {3, 1, 2}]];
```

Now let's create some "adjacency matrices".

```
m = Max[Max[Gpat[[All, 1]]], Max[Hpat[[All, 1]]]];
Gn = Max[Gpat[[All, 2 ;;]]];
Hn = Max[Hpat[[All, 2 ;;]]];
GA = SparseArray[Gpat -> 1, {m, Gn, Gn}];
HA = SparseArray[Hpat -> 1, {m, Hn, Hn}];
```

More precisely, `GA[[i]]` is the adjacency matrix of the subgraph of `G` that consists precisely of those edges with label `i`. Same for `HA[[i]]`. In my understanding, the respective adjacency matrix `HA[[i]]` of the labeled product graph is essentially the Kronecker product of `GA[[i]]` with `HA[[i]]`. So, let's generate it, extract its `"NonzeroPositions"` (these correspond to labeled edges in the new graph) and reorder again in order to obtain a list with entries of the form `{{i1,i2}->{j1,j2}, label}`.

```
GHA = ArrayReshape[
 SparseArray@MapThread[KroneckerProduct, {GA, HA}], 
 {m, Gn, Gn, Hn, Hn}
 ];
GHpat = GHA["NonzeroPositions"];
GH = Transpose[{Thread[GHpat[[All, 2 ;; 3]] -> GHpat[[All, 4 ;; 5]]], 
GHpat[[All, 1]]}];
```

My Haswell Quad Core laptop performs this task in 0.0346 seconds. However, 0.0313 seconds (more than 90%!) are used just for transforming from and into the inefficient data format (list of rules). So, the actual computation needs less than 0.0033 seconds. For `n = 500`, the pure computation needs 0.113 seconds while the final transformation into `GH` takes 0.926 seconds.

As I said in the beginning, I am not sure whether this is correct. But you have already an implementation, so that checking it should be easier for you than for me.

Comment: Hmm, very nice observation re: the tensor product of adjacency matrices. I'll have to think about that a bit more, but it seems very intriguing. I might have to rework other data structures to make full use of the benefits of packed arrays; will have to decide if that time savings is worthwhile. Thanks for the answer!